# How does elasticsearch fetch AND operator query from its indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, query-optimization

Suppose I have a AND/MUST operator query in elasticsearch on two different indexed fields
as follows :

```
"bool": {
    "must": [
        {
          "match" : {
            "query":      "Will",
            "fields":     [ "first",],
            "minimum_should_match": "100%"  // assuming this is q1
          }
        },
        {
          "match" : {
            "query":      "Smith",
            "fields":     [ "last" ]
            "minimum_should_match": "100%" //assuming this is q2
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I wanted to know how in background elastic search will fetch documents.
Whether it will get all id of documents where index matches q1 and then iterate over all which also has index q2.

or

It does intersection of two sets and how?.

How can I index my data to optimize and QUERIES on two separate fields?

Answer (score 3):

First some basics: ElasticSearch uses lucene behind the scenes. In lucene a query returns a scorer, and that scorer is responsible for returning the list of documents matching the query.

Your boolean query will internally be translated to lucene `BooleanQuery` which in this case will return `ConjunctionScorer`, as it has only `must` clauses.

Each of the clauses is a `TermQuery` that returns a `TermScorer` which, when advanced, gives next matching document in increasing order of document id.

`ConjunctionScorer` computes intersection of the matching documents returned by scorers for each clause by simply advancing each scorer in turns.

So you can think of `TermScorer` as of one returning an ordered list of the documents, and of `ConjunctionScorer` as of one simply intersecting two ordered lists.

There's not much you can do to optimize it. Maybe, since you're not really interested in scores, you could use a filter query instead and let ElasticSearch cache it.

Comment: @soulcheck...thanks for the info its helpful in case of term query, filter will help as it performs caching....if possible can you provide details how  intersection of two filters work?

Comment: @PrannoyMittal finding matching documents is exactly the same -  remember that in lucene filters are simply queries that don't participate in scoring (lucene starting with 5.x recommends using TermQuery to implement term filter).

Comment: Case in point, this is the `TermFilter` constructor in lucene 5.4.0: `public TermFilter(Term term) {
    super(new TermQuery(term));
  }`